# What difference does it make?

Tags: java, stack

This Question is related to the problem at hackerRank - https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-stack/problem

What difference does it make to put Stack inside while loop ?

If I put Stack inside loop, it return true for pattern '[]', but false 
if I do take it at class level.

The right answer should be true.

```
 import java.util.*;
    class Solution{

       public static void main(String []argh)
        {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


      while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
         String input=sc.nextLine();
           Stack<Character>  stack =  new Stack<>();
          for( char c : input.toCharArray() ){


              if( c == '{' || c == '(' || c =='['){
                  stack.push(c);
                  continue;
              }

              if( c == '}' && !stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() == '{' ){
                  stack.pop();
                  continue;
              }

               if( c == ')' && !stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() == '(' ){
                  stack.pop();
                  continue;
              }
               if( c == ']' && !stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() == '[' ){
                  stack.pop();
                  continue;
              }

              if( c == '}' || c == ')'|| c == '['){
                  stack.push(c);
                  break;
              }
   } //end for
          System.out.println(stack.isEmpty());
          } //end while



      } //end main


   } //end class
```

Comment: Outside the while loop the stack will check the whole input text instead of lines-by-lines.

Comment: oh okay :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop, a brand new stack will be created in every iteration of the while loop. If you put it at class level, only one stack will be created during the lifetime of the program.

This makes a difference only if you have multiple lines of input.

If you are only using one stack, then that stack will also include the brackets from the previous line of input, making this possible:

```
{
false
}
true
```

At first, I entered `{`. That does not balance, so `false`. In the next line, I entered `}`. It should not balance but the output is `true`. This is because the `{` from the previous line is still in the stack! That is why you should create a new stack for every line (every while loop iteration).

Another way to do this is to put the stack at class level, but call `clear` at the start of each iteration:

```
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        stack.clear(); // <----
        String input=sc.nextLine();
        for( char c : input.toCharArray() ){
```

Comment: Thanks, feels awesome.

Comment: If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that check mark! @AkankshaSingh